# Taxes on transfering money from India to the USA

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, capital-gains-tax, dtaa

I have an house in India and will be selling it soon. I need to transfer the money to the USA. I am in the USA and still have Indian citizenship.

How much tax will be involved?

Comment: are you a US tax resident?

Comment: Most, if not all, real estate transactions in India involve a substantial amount of money changing hands under the table, highly illegal though this is. I assume that transference of only the legal proceeds are being asked about. If you are a US tax resident, you will owe capital gains tax on the gains that you have, and what your gains are may be computed differently. For example, there is no "indexation" of the purchase price in the US (as is allowed in India): the indexation means that you have to pay Indian capital gains tax only on the excess over "inflation".

Answer (score 1):

The transaction will be taxable in India. You will have to pay Capital Gains tax. I am assuming that you purchased the house while you were Indian Resident for tax purposes. As such its needs more paper work to get the money back to US. Consult a CA in India who will help with the paperwork.

You haven't mentioned your tax status in US, one you update it, someone will post a US tax aspects of the transaction.